# Technical PHP - break and continue in the same loop

Tags: php, loops, break, continue

It is possible to use break/continue in 2 loops without variable ? (no continue 2; or break 2;)

Example doesn't work :

```
while(1) {
  // some code
  while(2) {
    // some code
    if(expr) {
      break; // break while(2)
      continue; // continue while(1) but never used
    }
    // some code
  }
  // some code
}
```

Solution with variable :

```
while(1) {
  // some code
  $continue = false;
  while(2) {
    // some code
    if(expr) {
      $continue = true;
      break;
    }
    // some code
  }
  if($continue) {
    continue;
  }
  // some code
}
```

Any solution with break / continue in the while(2) loop ? Another best way ?

Edit. Exemple with datas :

```
for($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $a = mt_rand(0, 1000);
    for($j=0; $j < 100; $j++) {
      if($j === $a) {
        break; // and continue the first loop
      }
    }
    echo "how to never display this string if second loop break?";
}
```

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly you shouldn't need a `continue` in your `while(1)` as once `while(2)` breaks, the loop would start again and subsequently restart `while(2)` until the condition is met again. The Cycle wouldn't end until you `break;` `while(1)`

Comment: I guess, just in case it needs to skip something inside, using `if(expr) continue;` will do

Comment: This code will be horrible to maintain and a total nightmare to every programmer.

Comment: lol i known, i don't make this code but i'm curious, juste a technical question. I write another code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the variables, just leave the continue out of the "while(2)" if "expr" is true it will break "while(2)" and continues with "while(1)".